# Can LogisticRegressionCV be used with StandardScaler?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameter

If we apply `StandardScaler` to transform the training data before we fit the `LogisticRegressionCV` model, I think it is incorrect because during cross validation the entire data has been used to scale the dataset. Thus knowledge of the test fold leaks into the training fold.

So is the solution using `StandardScaler` along with `LogisticRegression` in a pipeline and then using `GridSearchCV` to find the best parameter?

Comment: Yes, that prevents the leakage.

Comment: @gunes I was racking my head over how to implement scaling with `LogisticRegressionCV`, I guess it should be mentioned somewhere in the sklearn documentation so that people dont get confused

Comment: I think `LogisticRegressionCV ` is for people who doesn't even want to deal with CV code. Unfortunately, I've seen code in lots of places ignoring this leakage.

Comment: Note that the scores from the hyperparameter search shouldn't be treated as estimates of performance anyway, so the actual impact of the leakage is that perhaps somehow different levels of regularization get boosted test scores based on the leaked scale information.

Answer (score 2):

## Can `LogisticRegressionCV` be used with `StandardScaler` without data leakage?

No, it can't.

---

## Can `LogisticRegression` be used with Cross Validation and `StandardScaler` without data leakage?

Yes. As it is [stated in the LogisticRegressionCV documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html) (as explained below), that `LogisticRegressionCV` is equivalent to `LogisticRegression` used inside `GridSearchCV`.

So instead of using `LogisticRegressionCV` we can use `LogisticRegression` + `GridSearchCV`, which works in exactly the same way and produces exactly the same results, but this new duo is more modifiable and allows us to introduce `StandardScalar` the right way.

### Can you explain this workaround in more detail and provide an example?

Let's do it in three steps. First, investigate how LogisticRegressionCV is implemented by just using the documentation. Then, implement it ourselves. Finally, extend our implementation with the StandardScaler.

#### 1. Investigation

First, let's figure out how `LogisticRegressionCV` is implemented. From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html)

- It mentions (`"For the grid of Cs values and l1_ratios values"`) that a grid search is used, therefore we will use grid search as well, it's implemented as `GridSearchCV()`.
- For `l1_ratios` it says `Only used if penalty='elasticnet'`. The default value of `penalty` is `penalty=’l2’`, therefore `l1_ratios` is not optimized by default. Only `Cs` are searched.
- Default value of `Cs` is `Cs=10`. The documentation says, `If Cs is as an int, then a grid of Cs values are chosen in a logarithmic scale between 1e-4 and 1e4`. We can implement this behavior with `Cs = numpy.logspace(-4, 4, num=10)`
- We know that `the best hyperparameter is selected by the cross-validator StratifiedKFold`, but it's also used by default by the `GridSearchCV`, so we can ignore this.

#### 2. Create an equivalent to `LogisticRegressionCV`

Let's say we have this Logistic Regression example:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV

n = 100
X, y = make_classification(random_state=1, n_samples=n, n_features=5, n_informative=3, n_redundant=2)

model = LogisticRegressionCV()
model.fit(X, y)

print(f'Train set accuracy: {100 * sum(model.predict(X) == y) / n:.2f} %')
# Train set accuracy: 88.00 %
```

Putting our knowledge together, we can equivalently replace it with:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

n = 100
X, y = make_classification(random_state=1, n_samples=n, n_features=5, n_informative=3, n_redundant=2)

lr = LogisticRegression()
param_grid = {'C': np.logspace(-4, 4, num=10)}
model = GridSearchCV(lr, param_grid)
model.fit(X, y)

print(f'Train set accuracy: {100 * sum(model.predict(X) == y) / n:.2f} %')
# Train set accuracy: 88.00 %
```

#### 3. Extend with StandardScaler

We add the `StandardScaler` to the pipeline like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

n = 100
X, y = make_classification(random_state=1, n_samples=n, n_features=5, n_informative=3, n_redundant=2)

pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('lr', LogisticRegression())
])
param_grid = {'lr__C': np.logspace(-4, 4, num=10)}
model = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid)
model.fit(X, y)

print(f'Train set accuracy: {100 * sum(model.predict(X) == y) / n:.2f} %')
# Train set accuracy: 88.00 %
```

That's it!

Comment: What's the reason for the downvote?

Comment: This answer is misleading: the Q asks "can I use pipeline" and the answer states "it is incorrect, you need to use pipeline instead".

Comment: @Tim Thanks for your reply. The answer has now been revisited. The Q asks "can I use X to achieve Y" and the answer now states "no, it's not possible with X, but it is possible with Z", where Z is a straightforward native solution closest to X. Let me know if further changes are needed.

Comment: It wasn't my -1, I' just saying that the answer is a little bit confusing. There is a lot of text and code but it is hard to gather what exactly is the main message there.